# Why hibernate execute alter query to add foreign key

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, jpa

I'm studying JPA tutorial about @OneToMany.

When program started, hibernate log showed below code.

```
Hibernate: 
create table Member (
   id bigint not null,
    age integer not null,
    USERNAME varchar(255),
    TEAM_ID bigint,
    primary key (id)
)

Hibernate:     
create table Team (
   id bigint not null,
    name varchar(255),
    primary key (id)
)

Hibernate: 
alter table Member 
   add constraint FKl7wsny760hjy6x19kqnduasbm 
   foreign key (TEAM_ID) 
   references Team
```

Here, I wondered if Why hibernate use alter query to add foreign key?

If this is good, I wanna know why alter query is better than create query included to add foreign key.

```
// 1. Create table with foreign key

create table Member (
   id bigint not null,
    age integer not null,
    USERNAME varchar(255),
    TEAM_ID bigint,
    primary key (id),
    foreign key (TEAM_ID) references Team(id)
)


// 2. Create table and Alter table for foreign key

create table Member (
   id bigint not null,
    age integer not null,
    USERNAME varchar(255),
    TEAM_ID bigint,
    primary key (id)
)

alter table Member 
   add constraint FKl7wsny760hjy6x19kqnduasbm 
   foreign key (TEAM_ID) 
   references Team
```

---

This is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.2">
<persistence-unit name="hello">
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Team Class

```
@Entity
public class Team {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team")
    private List<Member> members = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Member Class

```
@Entity
public class Member {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    private String name;
    private int age;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TEAM_ID")
    private Team team;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason to create foreign keys after the tables is, that you don't have to get the order of the `CREATE TABLE` statements right. If you use the "inline" version for defining a foreign key, the referenced table must be created before the referencing table.

If you create all FKs as ALTER TABLE statements after **all** tables have been created, the order of the table creation doesn't matter.

This pattern makes the code that generates the DDL easier to write.

In case there are some circular references in the FK definitions (which is not a good design, but happens) this is the only way to define the tables and the foreign keys.

Comment: Thanks! This is clear to me. So.. is this pattern made by hibernate implementation ?